# Determining if a particle is in a box designated by four nodes of a mesh grid

Tags: python, physics, particles

**Python**

In my set-up, I have a meshgrid, with associated grid points. I have called this variable r_grid. Then I have generated particles, source points, etc. What I am trying to do, is deposit the particles onto the four surrounding nodes of that particular section of the grid that the particle finds itself in according to its distance from the nodes. Note that these source points are generated such that most of them end up in the middle (gaussian distribution). So far, I have written code to generate the grid, the source points, and the beginnings of specifying the four grid points that make up a section of the overall grid. My idea was that I can loop through each of the grid sections, determine if a source point is in it, then from there do some math that distributes the particle's charge as a function of r, the distance it is from each of the four surrounding nodes. I will post my code here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#creating grid
index = 3
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, index)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, index)

x_1, y_1 = np.meshgrid(x, y)

r_grid =  np.vstack((x_1.flatten(), y_1.flatten())).transpose()
r_grid.shape

print(r_grid)

# generating source points
# starting with a small number to start with
S = 1
r_s = np.random.randn(S, 2)/3.0
r_s.shape

# plots the four different nodes for the purposes of visualization
for i in range(len(r_grid)):
j = 0
if (i + 1) == (j + index):
    j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
else:
    plt.plot(x_1, y_1, 'bo')
    plt.plot(r_s[:, 0], r_s[:, 1], 'ro', linestyle='None', marker='.', ms=4)
    plt.plot(r_grid[i, 0], r_grid[i, 1], 'ro')
    plt.plot(r_grid[i + 1, 0], r_grid[i + 1, 1], 'bo')
    plt.plot(r_grid[i + index, 0], r_grid[i + index, 1],  'go')  
    plt.plot(r_grid[i + (index + 1), 0], r_grid[i + (index + 1), 1], 'mo')
    plt.show()
```

This is what I have so far! I have an idea of what the points correspond to in r_grid so that I can later use that information to loop through when I'm going sequentially through each section to determine if a particle is in said section and index i. If I can just get to the point where I can determine if a point is in the box that is specified, I think it'll give me a good start. I sort of hit a wall here so I thought I'd post it here! So, the question: how can I effectively loop through each square denoted by four nodes, and then determine if a particle (that has been randomly generated) is in that box? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if you want to do of this manner, you'll need to label the squares and then loop over them(Which might be not so efficient). There are some libraries that allows you to label regions, I think that `scipy`, `skimage` amoung other libraries have those functionalities.

I don't know if this may be a possibility in your problem, but maybe it would be more efficient take the position of the particle that were randomly generated and then take the edge points of the square where it belongs.

Here is a quick draft

```
particle_position = np.random.randn(S, 2)

particle_x_pos = particle_position[0,0]
particle_y_pos = particle_position[0,1]


#first x edge

first_x_edge = int(particle_x_pos)

#second x edge 

second_x_edge = int(particle_x_pos) + 1

#first y edge

first_y_edge = int(particle_y_pos)

#second y edge 

second_y_edge = int(particle_y_pos) + 1


#Now you have the edge points of the square where the particle belongs 

square_points = [[first_x_edge,second_x_edge],[first_y_edge,second_y_edge]]

print(particle_position)
print(square_points)
```

Note that this example only works for positive values, but is straightfoward to be modified to hold in the negative input values as well.